# How to update an object attribute in Priority Queue Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

If I have a class with four attributes and their getters and setters:

```
public class Shape {

    private int id;
    private int length;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    Shape(int id, int length, int width, int height){
        this.id = id;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

In my main class, I have a PriorityQueue of shapes ordered by height. My question is: how can I find an object in my PriorityQueue and update its length and width?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Comparator<Shape> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Shape::getHeight);
        PriorityQueue<Shape> shapes = new PriorityQueue<Shape>(comparator);
        shapes.add(new Shape(1,10,10,10);
        shapes.add(new Shape(2,20,20,20);
        shapes.add(new Shape(3,30,30,30);
    }

    //What I want to do is
    for(each element s in shapes){
        if(s.equals(shape){
            //update the length and width of element s in the priority queue
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I must implement it as a PriorityQueue

Comment: `PriorityQueue` is `iterable`. Therefore, you can have an `iterator` over it and iterate through it until you find the item you want.

Comment: You can of course stream it and find the desired item using `findFirst`

Comment: Just iterate, what are you worried about?